# copying files with a string in their name from one folder to another

Tags: command-line, bash

I have some files in a directory as follows.

```
source_dir: 
ABCD.HRA.0014.2.200.png
ABCD.HRA.0015.2.200.png
ABCD.HRA.0016.2.200.png
MMNP.HRA.0016.2.200.png
```

I also have a text file with following content.

```
text.txt:

ABCD.HRA.0014
ABCD.HRA.0015
```

Now is there any way I can transfer the files as per the string mentioned in `text.txt`.
After `command`, `source dir` and `dest_dir` should be as follows.

```
source_dir: 
ABCD.HRA.0016.2.200.png
MMNP.HRA.0016.2.200.png

dest_dir: 

ABCD.HRA.0014.2.200.png
ABCD.HRA.0015.2.200.png
```

Comment: how many items is there in the source_dir? it looks big

Comment: Wouldn't that be ***moving***, not *copying*?

Answer (score 14):

`grep -f` allows you to use text.txt as a source for patterns.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash  
for i in source_dir/*.png; do  
  if grep -Fq -f text.txt <<< "$i"; then  
    mv -t dest_dir "$i"  
  fi  
done
```

```bsh
$ ls
dest_dir  script.sh  source_dir  text.txt
```

grep options:

- `-F` Interpret patterns as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
- `-q` Do not write anything to stdout.
- `-f` Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.

Here strings:

- `<<<` A variant of here documents, does variable expansion before sending the string.

mv options:

- `-t` Move all source arguments into `-t` directory.

Comment: here xx is a random don't care string. But it seems like in your answer xx on both sides is fixed.

Comment: are there underscores in those parts?

Comment: no. It should be like 'dontcaretext{stringtofind}dontcaretext'. the dontcaretext can be anything and of any length and is not same in all files.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the real example.

Comment: Bu using the above comment, it moves all the files instead of just those mentioned in text.txt.

Comment: Inefficient: you start a process for each file in a possibly large directory, and each time you scan a possibly large collection of patterns.

Comment: `ls -1 | grep -F -f text.txt | xargs -n 4096 mv -t dest_dir`

Comment: think you need to loop one or the other

Comment: Next you dont need to use fixed string, then you can consolidate patterns so two could be one `^ABCD\.HRA\.001[4-5]`

Answer (score 11):

Your files all seem to end in `.2.200.png`, hence we can use the input file only:

```
while read line ; do
  mv "source_dir/${line}.2.200.png" destination_dir/
done < text.txt
```

Comment: wow very simple, good!

Comment: Even simpler: taking the OP to the letter, `mv "source_dir/*${line}*" destination_dir/` (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Another way using find:

```
find source_dir -type f | while read file; do  name=$(basename $file); grep ${name%.2.200.png} text.txt && mv -v $file dest_dir; done
```

Find file in `source_dir` and loops over the list.

For each file runs `grep` in `text.txt`. It is necessary to get the file name using `basename` command to exclude `source_dir` folder.

Finally if `grep` returns true, moves file in `dest_dir`.

Adding `-v` to `mv` command and removing `-q` to grep command, you can see the action.

---

Here is an examples of How to use it:

```
$ ls source_dir
ABCD.HRA.0014.2.200.png  MMNP.HRA.0016.2.200.png  shrr.2.200.png
ABCD.HRA.0015.2.200.png  sghd.2.200.png
ABCD.HRA.0016.2.200.png  shdj.2.200.png

$ cat text.txt
ABCD.HRA.0014
ABCD.HRA.0015

$ mkdir dest_dir

$ find source_dir -type f | while read file; do name=$(basename $file); grep ${name%.2.200.png} text.txt && mv -v $file dest_dir; done
ABCD.HRA.0014
`source_dir/ABCD.HRA.0014.2.200.png' -> `dest_dir/ABCD.HRA.0014.2.200.png'
ABCD.HRA.0015
`source_dir/ABCD.HRA.0015.2.200.png' -> `dest_dir/ABCD.HRA.0015.2.200.png'
```

Comment: Can you confirm it? I used it and it copies no file in destination directory

Comment: I added options that view the action. On my Linux Redhat system it works, but for now I don't have the possibility to test it on ubuntu

Comment: Updated with new file pattern.

Comment: If source has subdirectories containing some of the files, you _need_ `find` but if not, other methods will be faster.

Comment: This works but moves only the first file in text.txt.

Comment: Added example on how to use it

Comment: @WGroleau yes, of course, it depends on the situation. Since the OP did not specify the context, I also wanted to indicate this possibility. Undoubtedly loop through the file is more efficient if the files to be moved are few.

Comment: Right.  Thinking that readers might reject this due to running find repeatedly, I thought I should point out that sometimes the extra overhead might be necessary.  But other readers might not need it but not realize it isn’t necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Update: j4nd3r53n is correct: this won’t work for any file names that contain whitespace.  Apologies for my “senior moment”—what I intended (and have often done) was to pipe it to `while` as I have shown after.  I will not delete the wrong one as it may provide a useful warning to those that might try it.

One more flawed method (see warning above):

```
for STR in $(cat file); do # flawed
  cp "source/*${STR}*" dest
done
```

Here is the method I originally meant:

```
cat file | while read STR # better
  cp "source/*${STR}*" dest
done
```

Comment: The problem with this method is, if the filenames do have whitespace embedded, it won't work.

Comment: Not so.  I have done it often.  The quote marks cause everything between them to be treated as a unit.

Comment: `$(cat file)` will return a string of words separated by spaces, which `STR` will pick up as individual tokens. The quotes are not in effect at this point.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n, I’d be tempted to believe you if I hadn’t seen it work hundreds of times in my forty years of software engineering and home tinkering.

Comment: For anyone reading these comments, @j4nd3r53n is correct—I have edited a disclaimer into my answer.

Comment: want work either ... globbing will not expand inside quotes.

Answer (score 4):

One way, if you know all the filenames in the file contain no whitespace, is like this:

```
cp $(cat text.txt) targetdir/
```

I always add the `/` at the end - this makes the command fail if targetdir doesn't exist and is a directory; you want that to happen, because otherwise you may end up copying all the files into one called `targetdir` (actually, I think that doesn't happen anymore in modern `bash`; I'm that old)

If each line in the file contains one filename, which may contain whitespace, the this method works, at least in `ksh` and newer versions of `bash`:

```
cat text.txt | while read l
do
cp "$l" targetdir/
done
```

And if that doesn't work in your version of `bash`, then this does (note the `< text.txt` after `done`):

```
while read l
do
cp "$l" targetdir/
done < text.txt
```

Comment: +1 for correcting my goof.  To clarify a detail, though, if target did doesn’t exist and the slash is omitted, each file overwrites the previous, leaving only the last file copied.

Answer (score 3):

A bit convoluted, but you could use awk (which in this case does nothing more than reading the file out line by line)

```
awk '{system("mv " $0 "* dest_dir/")}' text.txt
```

which basically says 'for each line, do `mv BASE_STR* dest/`'

But the approach is very dependent on your specific use case, this might not work if you want to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
cat <list_file> | while read FILENAME; do ls -1 | grep $FILENAME | xargs -I xxx -P 0 cp -v xxx ../dest_dir ; done;
```

Comment: It would be better if you can a little bit of explanation.